# How can I add APK's split counterparts from Flutter to Google Play Store?

Tags: android, flutter, deployment, google-play

I finished a flutter app and want to publish it to store, but it's a small app with large size.

When I run: `flutter build apk` I got an APK with size 20MB.

I tried: `flutter build apk --split-per-abi`, I got 3 those 3 APKs:

```
✓ Built build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk (7.0MB).
✓ Built build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-arm64-v8a-release.apk (7.3MB).
✓ Built build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-x86_64-release.apk (7.5MB).
```

When I tried to add them to the store I couldn't upload more than 1 file.

How can I upload those APKs to google play store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best to build your app in app bundle format as the is the prefered format for Google PlayStore. Simply run this command in your terminal

```
flutter build appbundle
```

Also regarding shrinking the size of your released app, you can add obfuscation configuration to your android app. Follow these instructions on [Medium](https://medium.com/@swav.kulinski/flutter-and-android-obfuscation-8768ac544421) to enable obfuscation on your app.

However, [R8](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code) is the new code shrinker from Google, and it’s enabled by default when you build a release APK or AAB. Google removed the obfuscation configurations from the [Flutter: Build and release an Android app](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android) site and now show R8. But I found the old page [here](https://flutter.axuer.com/docs/deployment/android) which shows how to enable Proguard and obfuscation/and minification

I can't speak much on R8, but feel free to read [Flutter: Build and release an Android app](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android) before submitting your app to the PlayStore.

Answer (score 0):

for play store, you should build one APK without "--split-per-ab"

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this code in gradle :

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test.test"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64' // this one as policy changes
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
}
```